# Open MS RD Client with own App and rdp-File

Tags: android, android-intent, client, rdp

i have develope a programm for android to get rdp connections.

My problem is:
When i use ES File Explorer, i can open the rdp-file with "open with and choose RD Client" and it works perfectly, the app will show the login credentials.

In my program there is a button, when i click them it will open the RD Client app and it show a message: The rdp-file is not valid...

here is the code-fragment:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard1/SRV01.RDP");
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent i = new Intent();       
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setDataAndType(data, "application/*");
startActivity(i);
```

and my alternative:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.rdc.android");       
Uri data = Uri.parse("file://" + file);
LaunchIntent.setData(data);
LaunchIntent.setType("rdp");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

I didn't find the failure. I hope there is anyone who can help me.

Comment: Did you end up developing this app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.rdp");
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent i = new Intent();       
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setDataAndType(data, "application/rdp");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: An explanation of why the question code not work and what is your solution will be usefull.

Comment: I have made ​​the mistake that I have the path is not set statically. The error is in the first line of the code. Now, the Program works very well.

Comment: First as i replaced through ```getExternalStoragePublicDirectory``` RDP was able to read the settings file properly.